# problems using simple modal in chrome when zoom is applied

Tags: jquery, simplemodal

problems using simple modal in chrome (version 18.0.1025.142 m) when the zoom in chrome customize drop down is set to 90%. the modal never get full size.

Set the zoom level to 90% then click on one of the examples on the [simple modal web page](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/).

How can I work around this or is there a known fix/solution?

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround for the problem, and reported it here: http://code.google.com/p/simplemodal/issues/detail?id=82